# java/drools : :java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to bind property

Tags: java, drools

I am facing a problem in drools API which is causing the exception, this code was previously working and there is no change in the rule code: java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to bind property rule code is :

```
rule "Rule Name Imp" 
agenda-group "Agenda 1" 
salience 1000 

when     $tbl1 : TABLE_MAIN( COL1  == "ABC" )          

not TABLE_MAIN(TABLE_MAINID == $tbl1.TABLE_MAINID,             
               DATECOLUMN > $tbl1.DATECOLUMN )      

$cnl: TABLE2 (SS_COL == $tbl1.TABLE_MAINID,                                  
              DATECOLUMN == $tbl1.DATECOLUMN,                                 
              QTY == null )      

then     

$cnl.QTY = 0;    
update($cnl);     

 end
```

Comment: binding a property usually involves a configuration file associate parts of the code file.

Comment: I have not touched the part of the code so, I was wondering if this can be the behavior of the drools